# incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[128]' from type 'char *'

Tags: c, syntax, struct

I'm trying to assign char* field to char* field, but get this error:

`incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[128]' from type 'char *'`

how can I fix this? and why is that happening?

```
    AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *context = (AddressItem_Callback_ContextType *)malloc(sizeof(AddressItem_Callback_ContextType));

   //check if icons need to be downloaded
   if (pEntity->cBigIcon[0] != 0){
      if (res_get(RES_BITMAP,RES_SKIN, pEntity->cBigIcon) == NULL){

          context->Icon = pEntity->cBigIcon;
          context->iID = pEntity->iID;

         res_download(RES_DOWNLOAD_IMAGE, pEntity->cBigIcon, NULL, "",TRUE, 1, addressItem_icon_download_callback, context );
      }
   }
```

declarations:

```
typedef struct
{
    int  iID;        //  POI Type ID
    int  iExternalPoiServiceID; // Service ID
    int  iExternalPoiProviderID; // Provider ID
    char cBigIcon[MAX_ICON_LENGHT];
    char cSmallIcon[MAX_ICON_LENGHT];
    char cBigPromotionIcon[MAX_ICON_LENGHT];
    char cSmallPromotionIcon[MAX_ICON_LENGHT];
    char cOnClickUrl[MAX_URL_LENGTH];
..
} RTExternalPoiType;

typedef struct
{
    int  iID;        //  POI Type ID
   //int  iExternalPoiServiceID; // Service ID
   // int  iExternalPoiProviderID; // Provider ID
    char Icon[MAX_ICON_LENGHT];
} AddressItem_Callback_ContextType;
```

Comment: Arrays are not pointers.  You cannot assign to an array.

Comment: but both of them are arrays

Comment: You still can't assign.  You'll need to use `memcpy`.

Comment: You can't assign an array to another using just the assignment operator.

Comment: Use strcpy() to copy the string pointed by char* to your field.

Comment: @eladbenda No, one is an array, the other one is a pointer. But anyway, you couldn't assign to an array even if the RHS is an array too, because it doesn't make sense.

Comment: @eladbenda Note that the answer you accepted is **wrong** (i. e. the reasoning of its author is incorrect as he misundertands the whole concept). Consider revising your decision.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Array names are constant pointers you can not modify them. In this scenario Icon is a constant pointer and

```
            context->Icon = pEntity->cBigIcon;
```

here you are trying to modify it, which is not allowed.

Try this ..

strcpy(context->Icon,pEntity->cBigIcon);

Comment: Icon is not so much a 'constant pointer' as 'an array', and you simply can't assign to arrays like that.

Comment: int Icon[5];
I am not sure but this is what I think compiler do when we declare an array .. 

int* const Icon=(int*)malloc(5*sizeof(int));

Comment: Your understanding of "what compiler does when declaring an array" is incorrect. Array is not a constant pointer and there's no `malloc` involved. When array type decays to  pointer type, the result of the decay is an rvalue. Rvalue of pointer type cannot be constant or non-constant. It is just an rvalue and this is why it is non-modifiable.

Answer (score 13):

You can't assign to arrays (as the error message states). **Copy** the strings instead:

```
snprintf(aStruct->member, sizeof(aStruct->member), "%s", someString);
```

Or, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot (prone to buffer overruns):

```
strcpy(aStruct->member, "the string");
```

Or, if you want to shoot yourself in the foot and not notice it (safe of buffer overruns, but doesn't NUL-terminate the string if too long):

```
strncpy(aStruct->member, "the string", sizeof(aStruct->member));
```

Comment: +1 for mocking `strncpy()`.

Comment: @unwind :D The usual security warning would have been boring. Too bad OP accepted a wrong answer.